# Parse objects are not deleting

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse as baas , I was using below code to delete objects .But tommorow i  came to know that this piece of code is not working .

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setIcon(R.drawable.main).setTitle("Delete this product ?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Delete this product ?").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {



                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("VendorInv");
                    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", details.getObjectId());
                    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                            try {
                                object.delete();       // fixed part
                                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {   // fixed part
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {

                                        if (e == null) {
                                            vendorDetailsList.remove(position);
                                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, vendorDetailsList.size());
                                            count.setText(String.valueOf(vendorDetailsList.size()) + "/" + totalNo + " items are Online");
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                Log.i("sand", e1.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();


        }

    });

}
```

Then as a contributor of parse android  said than i fixed this part of code below

```
    holder.cross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setIcon(R.drawable.main).setTitle("Delete this product ?")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Delete this product ?").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("VendorInv");
                        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", vendorDetailsList.get(position).getObjectId());
                        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
 /* this part is changed */                               object.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Log.i("sand", vendorDetailsList.get(position).getObjectId());
                                            vendorDetailsList.remove(position);
                                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, vendorDetailsList.size());
                                            count.setText(String.valueOf(vendorDetailsList.size()) + "/" + totalNo + " items are Online");
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Not Deleted please check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });


                    }

                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();


            }

        });
```

Toast is printing deleted but still object is not deleted in database.
I dont know where i am going wrong, but this is not helping me in deleting an object
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is parse.com is still running. As i read this article http://blog.parse.com/announcements/a-parse-shutdown-reminder/ a time ago that its going to shut down.

Comment: now its open source and i am using heroku as  backend . So yes its still working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config your class `VendorInv` on the server to be "Public Read and Write enabled"
and use next code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("VendorInv");
    query.getInBackground(vendorDetailsList.get(position).getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object != null) {
                object.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.i("sand", vendorDetailsList.get(position).getObjectId());
                            vendorDetailsList.remove(position);
                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, vendorDetailsList.size());
                            count.setText(String.valueOf(vendorDetailsList.size()) + "/" + totalNo + " items are Online");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Not Deleted please check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have used this  , and it is also printing a toast "Deleted" .But Its not deleting in database.Any guesses can it be because of ACL but i have set it to Public for now

Comment: Then I guess there is some issue on the server side

Comment: so sorry my bad there is an error,
`2017-08-25T07:13:22.134Z - Permission denied for action delete on class VendorInv.
2017-08-25T07:13:22.128Z - Error generating response. ParseError {
  code: 119,
  message: 'Permission denied for action delete on class VendorInv.' }`

Comment: Maybe you should config that class on the server to allow clients delete objects

Comment: Thank you i solved it , i have set CLP to not delete in public  .

Comment: Glad to help. I've edited the answer, could you mark it as answered, thanks!